# How to setup port to subdomain in AWS?

Tags: apache2, proxy, docker, amazon-ec2, aws

I have a domain (e.g. example.com) registered with godaddy.com and use AWS for hosting. Nameserver on Godaddy later added to AWS

[image]

I have an ubuntu (t2.medium) apache server installed. My project in Docker has LAMP, ELK, Node, React, and Postgres installed. Everything works on the local system using direct ports. Few ports open in my project i.e.

- example.com:3000 react app [frontend]
- example.com:5601 kibana app
- example.com:5050 postgradmin app
- example.com/radius php application [backend]
- example.com:8080 phpmyadmin app

my desired URLs are:

- example.com:3000 react app [frontend] => http://example.com
- example.com:5601 kibana app => http://kibana.example.com
- example.com:5050 postgradmin app => http://postgradmin.example.com
- example.com/radius php applicatinn [backend] => http://example.com/radius
- example.com:8080 phpmyadmin app => http://phpmyadmin.example.com

I have tried a few things but nothing is working. on route53
[image]

tried reverse proxy on apache by adding separate conf files e.g.

default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName example.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

kibana.conf

```
Listen 5601

<VirtualHost *:5601>
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    ServerName kibana.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

pgadmin.conf

```
Listen 5050

<VirtualHost *:5050>
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    ServerName pgadmin.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

when I run docker-compose up on EC2, http://example.com/radius works fine. but others do not (e.g. http://kibana.example.com). but if try with port directly (e.g. example.com:5601) it's working. but I want to use a sub-domain not a domain with a port.

How to do that?

reverse proxy I tried as mentioned in the description but it's not working properly

Comment: Using a reverse proxy is absolutely required for your use case. Within docker I recommend using [traefik](https://doc.traefik.io). It is a bit tricky to configure.  Additionally I recommend a wildcard DNS and a wildcard certificate if you want to use https instead of http.

Comment: thanks... will check and update :)

Comment: This question should not belong here as it is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @dummyuser thanks for the suggestion, I added traefik in docker. The local env is working great with multiple subdomains, now checking on route 53.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, comment please if this approach is wrong.

Added my sub-domains in AWS route53:

[image: aws-route53]

In docker-compose.yml file, added [traefik](https://traefik.io/) and added my other images on the same network (**t2_proxy**)

```
traefik:
  image: "traefik:v2.9"
  container_name: $DOCKER_IMAGE_TRAEFIK
  command:
    #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
    - "--api.insecure=true"
    - "--providers.docker=true"
    - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
    - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "8080:8080"
  labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`$DOCKER_TRAEFIK_HOST_PROXY`)
      - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal
    #  - traefik.port=8080"
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
  networks:
    - t2_proxy
    - postgreNetwork
    - elk
```

In this config, $DOCKER_IMAGE_TRAEFIK is traefik image name from my .env file. You can add your image name and $DOCKER_TRAEFIK_HOST_PROXY is the host name e.g. proxy.example.com

for port configuration:

```
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin:latest
  platform: linux/amd64
  container_name: $DOCKER_IMAGE_PHPMYADMIN
  links:
    - mysqldb
  networks:
    - t2_proxy
  environment:
    PMA_HOST: mysqldb
    PMA_PORT: ${MYSQL_PORT:-3306}
  # ports:
    # - "${PHPMYADMIN_PORT:-7865}:80"
  labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.rule=Host(`$DOCKER_TRAEFIK_HOST_PHPMYADMIN`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.entrypoints=web"
    - "traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin-rtr.tls=true"
    - "traefik.port=$PHPMYADMIN_PORT"
  volumes: 
    - /sessions
```

In this config, $DOCKER_IMAGE_PHPMYADMIN is phpmyadmin image name and $PHPMYADMIN_PORT is 7865 from my .env file. You can change as you want. $DOCKER_TRAEFIK_HOST_PHPMYADMIN is the host name e.g. phpmyadmin.example.com

In this example. I have blocked port access and I can access the sub-domain properly. the same setting for LAMP, ELK, Node, and React in my project.